# Ошибка при компиляции. Функции С++

Tags: c++, функции

Ошибка компиляции - неинициализированная локальная переменная (a,b,x,y...). Почему функции не связаны, если использован файл заголовков?

first.cpp

```
    #include "func.h"
    #include <cmath>
    
    float func(float a, float b)
    {
        float y, x, k;
        const float pi = 3.14;
        int Z;
        a = (pow(k, 1 / 4)) / x + (exp(y - 1)) / abs(5 * k + pow(x, 3)) - cos(Z * pi / 180) + tan(15 * 180 / pi);
        b = (10 + cbrt(pow(y, 5) + 2 * x)) + 4 / pow((3 * y - x), 3) + (pow(abs(y - x), 3)) / 3;
        return a;
        return b;

}
```

second cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "func.h"
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, b, x, y;
    int Z;
    cout << "Enter x: "; cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter y: "; cin >> y;
    cout << "Enter Z(integer): "; cin >> Z;
    a = func(a, b);
    b = func(a, b);
    cout << "A: " << a << endl;
    cout << "B: " << b;
}
```

h file

```
#pragma once
float func(float, float);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

конечно неинициализированная

у вас код

```
float a;
a = func(a, b);
```

и что должно передаваться в качестве параметров функции?

и вот это так не работает:

```
float func(float a, float b)
{
    return a;
    return b;
}
```

после первого `return` произойдет выход из функции и возврат управления основному коду

если уж вы хотите внутри функции менять внешние переменные - используйте ссылки

```
void func(float& a, float& b)
{
}
```

кстати в вашей функции `func` присутствует также ЛОКАЛЬНАЯ переменные `y, z, k, Z`, которые объявлены, но не проинициализированы.

Comment: Даже если бы не было строк a=func (a.b),  b=func (a.b), ситуация бы не изменилась. Спасибо за ответ, сейчас попробую разобрать.

Comment: А как использовать полученные данные из cin первой функции во второй функции ?

Comment: не понял? вы же все данные от пользователя получаете ДО функций, ну так и передавайте их дальше в качестве параметров. Вы бы общую задачу еще описали бы - тогда стало бы понятно что делать, потому что тут возможно не ошибки править надо, а кардинально переделывать логику

Comment: Я пытаюсь узнать почему данные из int main не доходят до void func? В void func, они неинициализированные. Как передать данные которые ввел пользователь в main в функцию void func?

Comment: функция `main` отдельно и переменная `a` для нее локальна - функция `func` их не видит, переменная `a` внутри функции `func` локальна и функция `main` их не видит. Вы вызываете func(a) из функции `main` при том, что `a` в функции `main` не инициализирована к тому моменту, дальше внутри функции вы меняете значение переменной `a`, которая локальна для функции `func` и никак не затронет переменную `a` из функции `main`.  Пользователь ввел x, y, Z - ну так и передайте `void func(float x, float y, float Z)`

Comment: но вы же хотите еще и получить в `main` значения `a, b` , которые вы меняете внутри функции `func` - для этого можно передать их по ссылкам и тогда ваша функция будет `void func(float &a, float &b, float x, float y, float Z)` и после отработки функции в `main` появятся значения `a, b`

Comment: Крайне Вам благодарен за подробное обьяснение, спасибо что уделили столько времени.